# Загрузить другой трек после остановки WMPLib C#

Tags: c#

Отлавливаю событие остановки трека таким вот методом:

```
public void PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if (NewState == 8)//окончание трека
    {    
        Music.WMP.URL = trackUrl;
        WMP.controls.play();
    }
}
```

Это событие вызывается, когда трек закончен, далее я пишу корректную ссылку на другой трек, однако `WMP.controls.play();` не дает никакого результата. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: какой API это Кинь мне весь код я посмотрю.

Comment: Подрубаю либу WMPLib если ты об этом. Если переопределить `Music.WMP = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();` то тогда все работает.

Comment: Может перед запуском нового трека надо остановить принудительно предыдущий? Или открыть новый сначала